# How can I use jquery to toggle "checked" for radio buttons within clickable table cells?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have several forms that have radio buttons and checkboxes embedded in tables.  I want two use jquery to do two things:

- First, the user can "click" a radio button or checkbox by clicking the table cell that contains the button.
- Second, the user can toggle checkboxes **and** radio buttons by clicking twice.  Thus, clicking an already-checked radio button (or the cell containing it) should **un**-check it, leaving no radio button selected within the group.

I can do both of these separately, but I'm stuck on getting them to work together.  Please help!

Here's my not-quite-working jquery code:

```
$(".clickable", Q)
    .mouseover( function(){ $(this).addClass('mouseover-cell'); })
    .mouseout( function(){ $(this).removeClass('mouseover-cell'); })
    .click( function(event){
        if( event.target.type != 'checkbox' && event.target.type != 'radio' ){
            var x = $('input', this).attr("checked");
            $('input', this).attr("checked", !x);

            //$('input', this).trigger("click");
        }
        return false;
    });
```

The html for a single button looks something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    Label for the button group
  </td>
  <td class="clickable">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1">
  </td>
  <td class="clickable">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="2">
  </td>
  <td class="clickable">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="3">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: try `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` for checked

Comment: Thanks!  This gets a lot closer, but not quite there.  It fails in the case where I try to de-select a radio button by clicking the button itself (not the table cell).  AFAICT, everything else works!

Answer (score 2):

Your code wrks fine with a slightly different layout.

You can test it here

[Clickable cells](http://jsfiddle.net/slfede/XzEfg/)

```
$(".clickable").mouseover( function(){ $(this).addClass('mouseover-cell'); });
$(".clickable").mouseout( function(){ $(this).removeClass('mouseover-cell'); });
$(".clickable").click( function(event){
    if( event.target.type != 'checkbox' && event.target.type != 'radio' ){
        var x = $('input', this).attr("checked");
        $('input', this).attr("checked", !x);
    }
    return false;
});​

<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>
    Label for the button group
  </td>
  <td class="clickable">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1">
  </td>
  <td class="clickable">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="2">
  </td>
  <td class="clickable">
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="3">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

Comment: No, this doesn't fix it -- try clicking the radio buttons themselves.

Comment: which browser are you using? Do you have jQuery? it works fine on chrome both clicking the cell or clicking the radio button. Did you try the link I posted?

Comment: I'm using Chrome v20, with jquery, and I did try the link.  The problem is *unselecting* a radio button by clicking the button itself.